# Expressions Web 2 - rewriting code

Tags: asp-classic, expression-web

One of our designers is looking at Microsoft Expressions Web, mainly to evaluate it against Dreameaver for maintaining the web based interfaces to our projects, and we've found a behaviour that we can't explain and can't believe is correct - it seems to be altering code in some cases.

A small example that shows the issue is:

```
<frameset rows="<% =MenuHeight %>,*" cols="*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0" id="fsOuter">
</frameset>
```

which it converts to:

```
<frameset rows="*,*" cols="*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0" id="fsOuter">
</frameset>
```

instantly upon loading the file to edit. In this case it is removing the rows attribute from the frame, in the larger example that this was cut from it replaced it with rows="*,*" instead.

Are we missing something simple like a "don't throw away our code please" option, or is there something in the above example that is triggering the behaviour? Or does this simply mean that Expressions Web is not a suitable program for maintaining our old ASP based code?

Answer (score 1):

"simply mean that Expressions Web is not a suitable program for maintaining our old ASP based code"

I'm going with that.